# Using Get-Service where service name has square bracket

Tags: powershell, service, sas

I would like to start and stop particular services using a PS script. When I use the following:

```
Get-Service "SAS [SASConfig-Lev1] SASMeta - Metadata Server" | Where {$_.status –eq 'Stopped'} | Start-Service
```

I get the error:

```
Get-Service : The specified wildcard character pattern is not valid: SAS [SASConfig-Lev1] SASMeta - Metadata Server

At line:1 char:1

+ Get-Service "SAS [SASConfig-Lev1] SASMeta - Metadata Server" | Where  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-Service], WildcardPatternException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetServiceCommand
```

The problem isn't in the Where clause because if I remove it I get the same error.

```
Get-Service "SAS [SASConfig-Lev1] SASMeta - Metadata Server" | Start-Service
```

I've tried this

```
Get-Service 'SAS [SASConfig-Lev1] SASMeta - Metadata Server' | Start-Service
```

and this

```
Get-Service "SAS [SASConfig`-Lev1] SASMeta - Metadata Server" | Start-Service
```

but get the same error.

Any suggestions about how to include dashes in the service name and have `Get-Service` to run without errors?

Answer (score 4):

You need to do some escaping in order to get the square brackets into the service name value.  In the sample `Get-Service` command the two leading grave marks (``` `` ```) before the opening bracket is not a mistake.  The escaping convinces the [Get-Service command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service?view=powershell-7) parsing to **not** see the first argument as containing wildcards.

```
Get-Service "SAS ``[SASConfig-Lev1] SASMeta - Metadata Server"
```

Example from my powershell console:

```
> Get-Service "SAS ``[BIserver-Lev1] Web Infrastructure Platform Data Server" | Format-List


Name                : SAS [BIserver-Lev1] Web Infrastructure Platform Data Server
DisplayName         : SAS [BIserver-Lev1] Web Infrastructure Platform Data Server
Status              : Running
DependentServices   : {}
ServicesDependedOn  : {RPCSS}
CanPauseAndContinue : True
CanShutdown         : True
CanStop             : True
ServiceType         : Win32OwnProcess
```

[**Wildcards**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7)

```
PowerShell supports the following wildcard characters:

Wildcard  Description   
*         Match zero or more characters
?         Match one character in that position
[ ]       Match a range of characters i.e. [a-j]
[ ]       Match specific characters   i.e. [adrstz]
```

Comment: I would guess the `\`\`` is reduced to `\`` when the command line is parsed and the `\`` escapes the bracket with in the Get-Services interpretation itself